# How to create a task under a batch job via ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I've created one batch account(**demo-batch-account**) and one batch job(**TEST_JOB**).
and created relevant application pool and package all are mapped.

Consider,
Application pool name: **DemoTestPool**
Application package name: **TestTool.zip**
To be run command as: `cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_TestTool#1%\TestTool.exe`

Now, this command I need to run by adding new Task under TEST_JOB via ADF pipeline.
Kindly suggest me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you please specify which pool you are talking about, is it SQL pool?
2. im not sure if i understand your question , do u want to create a dynamic task and run the package in this task , or create a task and add a command to run the package? (the second one makes more sense to me)

unfortunately ,there are no built-in activity to run zip files yet , but you can do it using **Custom Activity**.

**if you want to run your package using ADF pipline , you need to do 3 things :**

- create a pipline ,in ADF,on the left side open:
  Author hub -> piplines -> click on new pipline -> in search tab type "custom activity" and drag it to the board.
- click on Custom activity , under settings tab , you can write the command that you need such as : "cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_TestTool#1%\TestTool.exe"
- click on validate + debug and make sure you configure the custom activity correctly

please check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity